# Selenium Java : Side bar menu navigation - > Unable Select the un-ordered list menu item

Tags: java, html, selenium

I am trying an alternative way to select a menu item in the sidebar navigation. These elements are within an iframe. I have switched to the iframe and am trying to select an item from the side menu in order for the respective navigational items to be displayed for selection. These menus are sitting in a `<ul>` tag. You will notice that by default the very first menu/list item is selected. I am trying to select Customers. I am using Selenium webDriver for Java. See the screenshot with the HTML.

I have tried the following already, and other `xpaths` with no success:

1. Xpath-`//*[@class='crm_sitemap_catalog_item' and contains(text(),'Customers')]`
2. Xpath-`//*[@id="catalog"]/ul/li[5]/div[2]/div`
3. Full Xpath- `//html/body/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[5]/div[2]/div`
4. CSS Selector-`#catalog > ul > li.crm_sitemap_catalog_item.selected > div.body1 > div`

This is one example of the error message that is returned:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class='crm_sitemap_catalog_item' and contains(text(),'Customers')]"}
```

I would get the same error using alternative xpath values.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to follow the top menu navigation approach and it works as follows:

```
 public void PerformItemNavigation(WebElement onWebElement , WebDriver mydriver) {
    Actions objectAction = new Actions(mydriver);
    Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) mydriver).getCapabilities();
    String browserName = cap.getBrowserName().toLowerCase();

    switch (browserName){
        case "chrome":
                objectAction.moveToElement(onWebElement).perform();
                objectAction.moveToElement(onWebElement).click().perform();
            break;
        case "firefox":
            ((RemoteWebDriver) 
            mydriver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", onWebElement);
            objectAction.moveToElement(onWebElement).build().perform();
            objectAction.click();
            objectAction.perform();
                break;
           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below `XPath`

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
LiOption = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Customers']/parent::div/parent::li")))
action.move_to_element(LiOption).click(LiOption).perform()
```

Run it and let me know if you get any errors.

Comment: Ok, I will attempt this now quickly

Comment: Unfortunately this XPath value did not work, it also returns a NoSuchElementException. Thank you for trying to assist

Comment: Should I replace the parent values with the name of the actual element ? >parent::div/parent::li'<

Comment: Nope, it should have worked as it is. Is it possible to share URL?

Comment: `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
LiOption = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Customers']/parent::div/parent::li")))
action.move_to_element(LiOption).click(LiOption).perform()`

Comment: Thanks, I wish I could share the url, but I am not allowed to unfortunately, Ok I will try the above code too

Comment: Errors: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: //div[text()='Customers']/parent::div/parent::li                                                                            *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//div[text()='Customers']/parent::div/parent::li}
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor59.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

Comment: LiOption = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Customers']")))
action.move_to_element(LiOption).click(LiOption).perform()

Comment: My Java Syntax:                                                                                                 
 WebElement we=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locateIdentifier.IdentifyDynamicElementLocator(webElementType, webElementID)));
                                                                                                                           
 objectAction.moveToElement(we).click(we).perform();                                               So the parameters > webElementType =  XPath and webElementID = //div[text()='Customers']/parent::div/parent::li

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned the element you are trying to access is inside an iFrame so make sure you switch to iFrame first.

```
driver.switchTo().frame() //frame() is overloaded method so you can use which suits you.
```

Then make sure you wait for iFrame/ or wait for below element to load

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(div[title='Customers'])).click();
```

Comment: Thank you @Rakesh, I have switched to the iFrame and yet I am unable to locate this element. I have not resolved the issue yet